# copy constructor for queue seg fault

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, queue

I need to do the copy constructor for the queue class. 
Here's my code. I don't know why I got a seg fault!

```
Queue::Queue()
{
  front = NULL;
  rear = NULL;
  numItems = 0 ;
}

// Copy constructor                                                                                                                                                                
Queue::Queue(const Queue& queueToCopy)
{
  //QueueNode *newNode;//pointer to a new node                                                                                                                                       
  QueueNode *nodePtr;//traverse pointer                                                                                                                                            

  newNode = new QueueNode;
  nodePtr = queueToCopy.front;
  while (nodePtr != NULL){
    enqueue(nodeNode->value);
    nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
  }
}
```

////////////////////////////
This is the main function when i testing the copy constructor

```
int main()
{
  Queue obj; 
  //enqueue....
  ...
  // Testing Queue copy constructor                                                                                                                           
  Queue objQ2(objQ);
  cout << "The values in the queue objQ2 were: \n";
  while (!objQ2.isEmpty()){
  int value;
  objQ2.dequeue(value);
  cout << value << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: How does `newNode` ever get changed in the loop?

Comment: `newNode->value` might be being used uninitialized

Comment: It's really hard to say what the right code should be without seeing the declaration of the `Queue` class.

Comment: Why is this codedump + "why is xxx happening" getting upvotes?! This is a basic problem that can be solved with a debugger and a bit of working knowledge of the language

Comment: @redFIVE: hey, be nice! i am new to this. don't know how to use debugger yet.

Comment: so learn, there is no excuse not to, your example doesnt even compile. Your current edit has you operating on newNode but the declaration is commented out. That won't even compile

Comment: You cannot develop software without knowing how to debug.  You have a missing skillset that prevents you from doing programming.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you want to do with `newNode`, but your loop's condition seems wrong, because `newNode` seems get never changed in the loop. As @RSaha's comment, Maybe `newNode` is not needed, so:

```
while (nodePtr != NULL){
  enqueue(nodePtr->value);
  nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
}
```

Comment: `enqueue(nodePtr->value);`?

Comment: Thanks I change to (nodePtr != NULl) but I still get a seg fault when I called it in main

Comment: @RSahu So what does `newNode` do here?

Comment: @user3923936 See RSahu's comment, and try it again?

Comment: @user3923936 , first, research what causes seg faults, then, step through code with debugger.

Comment: @songyuanyao, `newNode` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like newNode can never be null so that loop continues until nodePtr = 0 in which case its next is invalid.  Also newNode->value needs to be initialized.

Maybe change it to while(nodePtr != NULL)